# How to user Mojo::UserAgent's connect_timeout

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojo-useragent

Perl newbie here. I have a line of code:

```
my $api_data = decode_json( $ua->get($url)->res->body );
```

where `$ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new`. On occasion, the request may hang (indefinitely) and I'd like to specify a connection timeout.

The [documentation](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent#connect_timeout) provides an example, but I'm not exactly sure how to incorporate it correctly into my statement.

How should I use `connect_timeout` in this case? I understand that Mojo specifies a default connection timeout value (10), but I'd rather specify it explicitly in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent#connect_timeout) shows that `connect_timeout` can be used as both a getter and a setter:

```
my $timeout = $ua->connect_timeout;    # getter
$ua         = $ua->connect_timeout(5); # setter
```

The setter returns the Mojo::UserAgent object it's called on so that it can be chained with other methods.

So you *could* do:

```
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

my $api_data = decode_json( $ua->connect_timeout(42)->get($url)->res->body );
```

But you're not required to chain methods, so I would recommend a more readable version:

```
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
$ua->connect_timeout(42);

my $api_data = decode_json( $ua->get($url)->res->body );
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple, straight-forward answer, and readability suggestions.